# SSIS - Disable Task Based on Variable Value

Tags: ssis-expressions, ssis-2008, data-flow

I have an SSIS package that runs a number of **Data Flow Tasks** all at the same time.

Each **Data Flow Task** is placed inside a Sequence Container.

Before the **Data Flow Tasks** are run, a **Script Task** is used to check what **Data Flow Tasks** are required to run.

Each **Data Flow Task** also has a related variable, which is set to true or false by the **Script Task**. The Data Flow Tasks use the variable value as a *Disable Expression* property.

When run initially, the process works as expected. Those Tasks that have variable value = true do run, and those that have a variable value = false do not run.

However, the next time I go to run the package all **Data Flow Tasks** are disabled initially (probably because the related variables are set to false).

But even when some variables are then set to true at runtime, the Tasks remain disabled. The *Disable Expression* does not seem to pick up the latest variable value. (in the Watch window I can see the variable values have updated correctly)

I tried setting '*DelayValidation*' *= true* on each Task but no change.

Any reason why this happens?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a script task at the beginning of the package, or right before the tasks in questions.

The script task should:

- Take in the Variables (like User::IsCounterpartyReportRequired)
- Display those variables in a message box (via MessageBox.Show(Variables.IsCounterpartyReportRequired.ToString())

This way you can see the variables at any stage of the package you wish, and find out if there is some other task that's making them change value.  It's a "quickwatch" style debugging but with MessageBox.

Just make sure you don't leave the messageBox Commands running before you deploy, as your package will fail.

Comment: In the Watch window I can see the variable values have updated correctly. I set a breakpoint right before the Tasks are to run and variables look good.

Comment: I'd still recommend a script task with a message box that evaluates your exact expression for the "Disable" attribute.  Either something is changing during package runtime or your expression is being set to the wrong value.  Also, is the check case sensitive? I see the "p" in "party" is lowercase but you seem to be using Pascal/Proper case.

Comment: Tried this but same issue. I am running in Debug mode in SSDT if that makes any difference?

Comment: @Kevin nope, that's exactly the mode i'd run it in.  Can you confirm the expression evaluation as well?  MessageBox.Show(IsCounterpartyReportRequired.ToString())  If it displays FALSE then this task SHOULD be disabled.  If it displays TRUE then the task should be ENABLED.

Comment: Disable Expression: @[User::IsCounterpartyReportRequired] == false

Comment: OK. It actually does work correctly. What was putting me off was the Data Flow Task appears disabled (greyed out) but the task is actually running so was difficult to determine this while debugging. Thanks for your help!